# Can I save current user using Insert Related Models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm thinking can I save the current user using `saveMany` function? Because I'm trying to save my current user in my `Comment` Model. Here's my code below. When I tried to submit the button it says.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_sender_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `document_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dasdsa, 161, 2016-07-29 17:11:05, 2016-07-29 17:11:05))

Controller:

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{

public function postComments(Request $request, Document $id)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    $commentObject = new Comment();

    $user = Auth::user();

    $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;

    $id->comments()->saveMany([$commentObject, $user->id]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

Model:

Comment

```
class Comment extends Model
{
protected $tables = 'comments';

protected $fillable =
[
    'comment',
    'document_id',
    'sender_id',
];


public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Comment');
}
}
```

User

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
  public function comments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) :

You should do it like this :

```
$id->comments()->saveMany([$comment1, $comment2]);
```

And before calling the `saveMany` method you should also add the `user_id` to the comment object :

```
$commentObject->sender_id = $user->id
```

And i think in your case you don't need the `saveMany` only `save` can be used :)

```
$id->comments()->save($commentObject);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it say's. `Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\Comment::$comment has no effect`

Comment: Hey this works!! Can you tell something on this part? `$commentObject->sender_id = $user->id?` Is the `sender_id` is the fillable in my Model or not?

Comment: Yes, it should be a fillable field. for this section `$commentObject->sender_id = $user->id` it's because you have a constraint 'comments_sender_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (sender_id) REFERENCES users (id)' if not the error will not be triggered but you will end with a comment that belongs to no body.